# Animate actions for camera and objects to play when exported as GLB?

Tags: animation, actions

I'm trying to make a camera animation as well as animations of specific objects in the scene, such that when it's exported as a GLB, the entire scene animation can simply play in the browser by playing all of the actions.

The thing is that when going to action editor after selecting the camera, and adding the keyframes, and playing it [plays fine for camera only], when I want to make an action for, say, a cube in the scene to move *while* the camera is moving also, I click "stash" for the camera action [or even when I don't similar result], then I click on the object I want to now animate, but as I add the keyframes to that object, when the timeline plays, the camera does not play at the same time

I understand that I can still add new keyframes to the object, and that when exported if I play all of the actions with code it should play it all together, but when I'm editing everything I want to be able to view the exact position of the camera while the other object[s] is moving

how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you use actions in the first place? I don't understand anything in your goal that requires them.

Comment: @L0Lock how else ca it be exported to a glb to play in the web?

Comment: I don't know if GLB requires to use actions, but other export formats don't. You can just animate everything on the same level. Actions are used only if you want to make isolated assets that need to be triggered independently or procedurally mixed together afterwards. Typically in video games.